# java library to parse regular expressions into a syntax tree

Tags: java, regex, lexical-analysis

I'd like a library that can take the string representation of a regexp and convert that into a syntax tree for easy programmatic manipulation. Something that would transform:

(\s?)bla[a-z]

into something like:

```
PARENTHESIS
  CHAR:SPACE
    WILD
WORD:bla
CHAR:a-z
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you're looking for is a syntax parser, right?

I would give a look on antlr (http://www.antlr.org/), you can create grammars and it will generate a syntax tree which you can walk, translate etc.

Comment: I am looking for a syntax parser FOR regular expressions, not WITH regular expression. I modified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: And there are some regex grammars available.

Comment: @jp Nobody said "with", it has some regex grammars.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I could do a with a regex grammar that I can pass to javacc or antlr. But it's hard to search for it as search results are all about using regex in antlr or javacc...

Comment: @jp There's a page with all the antlr grammars--maybe look there.

Comment: @DaveNewton I looked at http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list but couldn't find anything. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @jp. It looks like the ECMAScript 3 includes it. A naive Google search turns up [this](http://big-o.nl/apps/pcreparser/pcre/PCREParser.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) looks like a good choice for what you want to make.

It allows easy writing of grammars, way more easily than antlr or javacc.

Sample:

```
Rule Digit()
{
    return CharRange('0', '9');
}

Rule Integer()
{
    return OneOrMore(Digit());
}

Rule WhiteSpace()
{
    return ZeroOrMore(AnyOf(" \t"));
}

Rule NToMQuantifier()
{
    return Sequence(
        '{',
        WhiteSpace(),
        Integer(),
        Optional(
            WhiteSpace(),
            Integer()
        ),
        '}'
    );
}

Rule OtherQuantifiers()
{
    return Sequence(AnyOf("+?*"), Optional(AnyOf("+?")));
}

Rule Quantifier()
{
    return FirstOf(OtherQuantifiers(), NToMQuantifier());
}
```